# How to read .txt file 'sent' to javascript file by using operator '<' in cmd

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'd want to achieve something like this:

Running my `test.js` via node while sending `input.txt` to it

`node test.js < input.txt`

**test.js:**

```
var data = ??????;
console.log(data);
```

**input.txt**

```
abc
123
```

Is it possible?

Comment: have a look on https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  serevr.js 

  var fs=require('fs');
  fs.readFile('TestFile.txt','utf8',function(err,data)
  {
   debugger;
  if(err)throw err;
  console.log(data)

   });

  cmd
  >node sever.js
```

Comment: Brevity is accepted but an explanation is always more helpful :)